# What determines the size of a generator?

Tags: python, generator

```py
import sys

num_gen = (num for num in range(1))
print(sys.getsizeof(num_gen))
num_gen = (num for num in range(100))
print(sys.getsizeof(num_gen))

num_gen = (num+1 for num in range(100))
print(sys.getsizeof(num_gen))
num_gen = (num+1+1 for num in range(100))
print(sys.getsizeof(num_gen))
num_gen = (num+num for num in range(100))
print(sys.getsizeof(num_gen))
num_gen = (num+num+1 for num in range(100))
print(sys.getsizeof(num_gen))
```

OUTPUT

```
200
200
208
208
208
208
```

Why does the 4 generators below use 8 more bytes?

Comment: Added CPython tag since this behavior is a CPython implementation detail. FWIW, all cases print `112` in CPython 3.8 & 3.9, all `104` in CPython 3.10, the given behavior in CPython 3.11, and `192`x2 `200`x3 in CPython 3.12 on my system.

Comment: @Brian61354270 The question itself isn't implementation-specific even if the particular behaviour is.

Comment: @wjandrea The question is _"Why does the 4 generators below use 8 more bytes?"_ , which is CPython specific. I think the CPython tag applies.

Comment: @Brian61354270 Ah true, there are two questions being asked here. I'm going by the one in the title then, since it's broader. To put it another way, "What determines the size of a generator? **Specifically,** why [do] the 4 generators below use 8 more bytes?"

Comment: @henveloper Could you clarify what sort of answer you are looking for? Are you asking why in general the size of objects of the same type can vary, or why those specific generators have the sizes that they do?

Comment: Interesting point to note: the size of the generator object scales linearly with the number of nested parenthesized sub-expressions in CPython 3.11/12. In CPython 3.11, `sys.getsizeof(a + b + c + d + e + f for num in range(100)))` is 208, while `(a + (b + (c + (d + (e + f)))) for num in range(100))` is 240. Both generators have code objects of the exact same size with the exact same number of instructions. I'm guessing this is an artifact of the improved exception traceback messages that CPython 3.11/12 added, where the sub-expression in which the exception occurs gets underlined with `^`s

Comment: This question is implementation specific. The very notion of the generator - or an object in general - even having a size is tied to the implementation. Checking something like `sys.getsizeof` doesn’t make sense in an implementation like PyPy where the object may well not exist at all or have different practical memory size depending on the JIT warmup.

Comment: It looks like the difference in size is accounted for by changes in the size of the generators associated [frame object](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/frameobject.c#L963).

Answer (score 1):

A generator object's "size" isn't a function of the elements it will produce (like a list or some other kind of sequence), but of the code it executes to, well, *generate* the elements.

Comment: Also probably found the threshold to need more code when adding more to the expression body and padded for alignment. The additional `+1` and `+num` in the expression body would require additional instructions and potential additional overhead for some versions.

Comment: @JeffMercado AFAIK, the size of the generator object is independent from the size of its code object. The generator itself only needs to store a pointer to it. If you look at `num_gen.gi_code` for each of the generators in the question, you can see that the code object size varies among generators that report the same `sys.getsizeof(num_size)`. And if you look at `len(g.gi_code.co_code)`, you can see that the number of instructions varies more than `sys.getsizeof(num_gen)` can explain.

Comment: @Brian61354270 Well it appears to be a function of the expression complexity on my system. 3.11.5 x64 https://i.stack.imgur.com/njeFA.png Could probably work out the math for it if you look at the disassembly.

Comment: @JeffMercado I can replicate those results. But what's interesting is that its not the code object size that is causing the difference. If you create a monstrously large body like `AA+AB+AC+...+ZY+ZZ for _ in range(l)`, you still get `sys.getsizeof(num_gen) == 200` even though the code object is several kilobytes. The size also changes if you move around parentheses in ways that don't affect the number of instructions. And this only happens in CPython 3.11+. CPython 3.{8.9.10} don't see any changes in the size of the generator object at all, regardless of the body complexity.

Comment: I'm guessing this is an artifact of the improved exception tracebacks that CPython 3.11/12 introduced. The generator probably needs to store extra information about the layout of parentheses/sub-expressions to known which part of the body to underline with `^`s if an exception occurs.